What is と了承をとる? How is it used?

いいですか？

The character asks to his fighting partner about going for another round and she replies this

いいですかと問う形で、いいですよね、と了承をとるのはどうかと思いますが―…

What is exactly いですよね、と了承をとる? I think is "いいですかと問う形で、" like asking in the form of いいですか and どうかと思いますが is improper, but
What is she trying to say?

While いいですか is technically a question ("Is it okay?"), いいですよね is a confirmation ("It's okay, right?"). If asked this way, it would be harder for the listener to refuse it. She is pointing out that while her statement is technically in the form of a question, it's virtually a confirmation, and she has almost no choice but to obey in reality.

いいですかと問う形で、いいですよね、と了承をとるのはどうかと思いますが―…
Trying to seek consent like "It's okay, right?" in the form of a genuine question like "Is it okay with you?" doesn't seem right to me, though...

